# How to show the keyboard on Qt?

Tags: qt, keyboard

Any idea on how to show the keyboard when the focus is on a textbox? Just like android keyboard that is automatically appears when it is necessary. How can I do it on qt?

thanks!

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: I am using Qt4.7.1. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Are you using Qt Mobility? What physical device?

Comment: I am just a beginner and trying to create some application. I am only doing this using the simulator. What I wanted to use is the keyboard that is commonly used in mobiles.

Comment: Do you know what device you're emulating? I thought this showed up by default when a text field was focused.

Comment: I tried in maemo fremantle, Symbian^3 and Symbian Touch but it was not showed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you use QML you need invoke

```
Qt.inputMethod.show();
```

If you programming in pure C++ you need use method show() in same class QInputMethod.