# Disable Android keyboard in qml application

Tags: android, c++, qt, keyboard, qml

I'm porting an existing QML/C++ application to the Android system. The application is already running on the Android tablet, but I have issues with Android keyboard. 
Since my QML/C++ application has implemented its own keyboard, I would like to disable an Android one. 
I've tried to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` line in AndroidManifest.xml file, but keyboard still appears when I press an edit box.
Since I'm porting an existing application, I do not want to edit the code of application itself. The only things I can edit are AndroidManifest.xml, QtApplication.java and QtActivity.java files. `QtApplication` and `QtActivity` are derived from `Application` and `Activity` Android classes.

Is it possible to disable the Android keyboard globally for whole app at the startup of application(with editing manifest file or overriding `onCreate`, `onStart` or similar functions)?
Are there any functions in `Application` and `Activity` classes that I can override them and consequently disable native keyboard?

Comment: Does making your `editors` read-only an option?  Then you could use signals from your custom keyboard to populate/modify the text.

Comment: @phyatt, I’m sorry, I didn’t understand your question. My problem is when I press edit box, the Android software keyboard and my own keyboard both appear. The thing is that both are working, but my own is just hidden below the Android one. If I then close the Android one, I can use my own one. So the solution would be, to disable Android keyboard globally for my whole application, or to somehow catch/disable the signal that triggers the opening of the Android keyboard if it is possible to do this in QtApplication and QtActivity classes. But for now I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#readOnly-prop  If you change it to read only, then clicking on the editor or line edit, or whatever shouldn't send the signal.  The other option you are talking about is an event filter.  I'll find a link in a few minutes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724811/how-to-show-the-keyboard-on-qt

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#visible-prop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some time I found a solution, actually workaround for this problem. The idea was to consume an event that requests Software Input Panel (`QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel`). This event is sent by QML/C++ application to the host Android system.
So, I implemented an event filter called SIPRequestEater.

```
    class SIPRequestEater: public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    protected:
        bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
        {
            if(event->type() == QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel)
            {
                // filter out RequestSoftwareInputPanel event
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // standard event processing
                return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
            }
        }
    };
```

This filter has to be installed to `QCoreApplication` berfore the `QCoreApplication::run` is called.

```
QCoreApplication *coreApp = QCoreApplication::instance();
SIPRequestEater *sipRequestEater = new SIPRequestEater();
coreApp->installEventFilter(sipRequestEater);
```

It can be installed also on `QApllication`.

The problem is, that this filter does not catch `QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel` event. My explanation for this is that filters, which are installed with `QCoreApplication::installEventFilter(<filter>)` are filters only for input events, from Android to QML application. `QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel` is actually going in other direction, from QML application to the Android system. I didn't find out if it is possible to filter/disable output events. Because of this I decided to filter out the focus in event `QEvent::FocusIn` which actually causes `QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel`.For our application this works as it should. The Android keyboard is not appearing anymore and our edit text fields still get focus, because we have our own implementation of focus and keyboard. I believe that this is not the perfect solution for everyone, that's why I called it workaround.
If someone knows, how to filter out output events, specially `QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel`, please post it here.
The final implementation of filter is:

```
class SIPRequestEater: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
    {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn)
        {
            // filter out FocusIn event
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // standard event processing
            return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

QApplication::setAutoSipEnabled(false) disables the software virtual keyboard from popping up automatically. You can use the "Q_OS_ANDROID" preprocessor directive to avoid modifying behavior on your other target platforms:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
    a.setAutoSipEnabled(false);
#endif
    (...)
}
```

You can programmatically display or hide the virtual keyboard using this code:

```
QInputMethod* input;
input = QGuiApplication::inputMethod();

if(input->isVisible())
{
    input->setVisible(false);
}
else
{
    input->setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `setAutoSipEnabled` function is not available for `QGuiApplication` which is what you want when developing a Qml only app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using [Qt.inputMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html) - hide virtual keyboard immediately when it get visible for example by adding visibleChanged handler in qml root item

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    Qt.inputMethod.visibleChanged.connect(function () {
        if (Qt.inputMethod.visible)
            Qt.inputMethod.hide()
    })
}
```

With this approach it is also possible to add user interface setting to choose what keyboard to use (system or built in app).

**Update**:

Have figured out that sometimes there can be a blink of system virtual keyboard before hiding, especially when tapping to text input field to much. Handling visibleChanged in C++ don't solve this issue but seems to make it less frequently.

```
QObject::connect(QGuiApplication::inputMethod(), &QInputMethod::visibleChanged, [] {
    QGuiApplication::inputMethod()->hide();
});
```