# qt/qml android virtual keyboard z pozition

Tags: android, qt, keyboard, qml

I met the trouble with which I cant deal. I need to place the qml component (for example the Rectangle) above the native android soft keyboard. Is it real to do so?

Comment: Hello, could you provide more details about your problem and provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't change z of keyboard, because keyboard and your application are different apps, but you can  [disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275870/disable-android-keyboard-in-qml-application). Because lack of code in your question, I can guess that you have *[TextFiled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html)*, you can set it to *[readonly](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#readOnly-prop)* property.

Also you can check state of the keyboard and hide it, when it shows, but I'd not recommended this method